# Sharepoint 2010 Blog - Order rest query by Category

Tags: json, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've created a blog on Sharepoint 2010 and want to query the list via REST for reporting. I want to order the list by the default field Category (internal name PostCategory). Unfortunately, this is a multiselect field, therefore a simple "?$orderby=Category" doesn't work. I've also tried to expand the Category, but that doesn't work either.

Is there a chance, that I can order the list using rest? What about more then one selected Category? Can it be ordered by the first category, then the second, etc.?

If it's not possible using REST, what about ordering within JSON? I use a small javascript, that puts the list in a reporting format. Can I order within the JSON result?

Here is an example:

```
// Create REST-API URL
var strURL = "<REST-URL>";

// Get information from REST-API and create html output
$.getJSON(strURL, function(data) {
        <Create output>
    };

// Append to webpart
$('#<WebPartTitle>').append($(html));
```

EDIT: I've posted the question also [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/143388/sharepoint-2010-blog-order-rest-query-by-category), since it's happening all in sharepoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Category` field (`PostCategory` internal name) is a *multiple choice field*, in SharePoint REST it is **not** supported to apply `$orderby` query option to this type of field.

But you could sort returned items using JavaScript.

---

The following example demonstrates how to order `Posts` by `Category` field.

> There is one important note here:
>
> Since Category field is a **multiple** choice field value, it is
>   assumed that only *one category could be specified per post*.
>
> For that purpose `FirstCategoryTitle` property is introduced which
>   represent the title of **first** category in post item. This property is used > for sorting items

**Example**

```
var endpointUrl = 'http://contoso.intranet.com/blog/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Posts?$expand=Category';

$.getJSON(endpointUrl, function(data) {
   var items  = data.d.results.map(function(item){
       item.FirstCategoryTitle = (item.Category.results.length > 0 ? item.Category.results[0].Title : '');   //get first category
       return item;
   });
   items.sort(postComparer);   //sort by category
   items.forEach(function(item){
     console.log(item.Title);    
   });

});

function postComparer(x,y) {
  return x.FirstCategoryTitle > y.FirstCategoryTitle;
}
```

Comment: Nice, that did the trick! I had to play with the language discrepancies, but after that it was working immediately. Since I'm not so much into javascript, I don't get, how exactly it is working, espacially the function postComparer. But it shows, how powerful javascript is and I try to figure that out as well :-) 
Too bad, that it is not working directly using REST.